# Calling a method form one microservice to other

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, rest, microservices

I've classes like below in different projects.

Project1:

```
@Entity
public class ProductionCast {

    @Id
    private int movieId;
    private String actor;
    private String actress;
    private String director;
//setters and getters
}
```

Project2:

```
@Entity
public class MovieDetails {

    @Id
    private int movieId;
    private String movieName;
    private double collections;
//Setters and getters
}
```

the above classes are in different projects. "localhost:8089/productioncast/{movieId}" this is the url to get the details of production cast. i want to display the whole details of the movie from the above 2 classes by taking the input as movieId using RestTemplate. Any solution to this will be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the Microsoft Article on [**Communication in a microservice architecture**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/communication-in-microservice-architecture) It talks about the different [**Communication types**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/communication-in-microservice-architecture#communication-types)

Comment: I am not sure how your Application as a whole is designed but if you are having a ProductionCast Microservice and a Movie Microservice and want a website to display all the info for example then you would not have the Microservices talk to each other but instead your website would make http calls to query-endpoints (either directly or through abstraction) to each Microservice to get the relevant data and combine it into a single object for use in the website.

Comment: I've solved this thing thanks for your efforts. One more question I'm returning data in JSON format and it is displaying details of two different objects. as you can see I've movieId in different classes. i want to merge the two objects into one and return it. is this possible?

Comment: In our own implementations we would have a third object which is modeled with the properties the consumer (web,mobile etc..) cares about. We would map the properties we care about from the other 2 objects into that third object. You can pick the Movie id  from either but you should already have that anyway from the initial request, assuming it was the parameter passed to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping(path = "/mymoviedetails/{id}", produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody ProductionCast getProductionInfo(@PathVariable int id) {
        String url = "http://production-service:8089/moviedetails/"+id;
        Production cast = restTemplate.getForObject(url, ProductionCast.class);
        return cast;
    }
```